# My Tensor Flow C++ API does not produce constant in time calls for each sequential call to the session.run()

Tags: c++, tensorflow2.0

Working on Tensor Flow C++ API and each call sequential (approx. 100x) to session.Run() gets slower and slower until it is significant in the run time. Would like to know how to produce constant time code.

Tried the following and it starts off at 7620 microseconds but after 100 epochs the code takes
around 17000 microseconds and all it does is fill in a tensor. It gets linearly worst as the epochs goes higher.

I have attached the minimal reproducible code.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h>
#include <tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h>

using namespace tensorflow;
using namespace tensorflow::ops;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  //create a root scope
  auto scope {Scope::NewRootScope()};

  //create a session that takes our scope as the root scope
  ClientSession session(scope, SessionOptions());

  int epochs{100};
  for(int epoch=0; epoch<epochs; ++epoch){
    auto epoch_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
    Output out_ops=Fill( scope, {1,3}, Input(1.f));
    TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({out_ops}, &outputs));

    auto epoch_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> epoch_duration = epoch_end - epoch_start;
    auto epoch_microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(epoch_duration);
    std::cout << "Epoch Time taken: " << epoch_microseconds.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
  }
}//end of main
```